# Type Error $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a [jQuery Based Memory Game](http://www.slashc.com/codecanyon/jquery_memory_game/index.html) on my site. It works well overall but I want a "Play Again" Link and stats at the end to show. I cannot get that code to work. I see this error:

```
TypeError: $ is not a function
  [Break On This Error]     

    var game = $('div.slashc-memory-game'); // get the game
```

Here is the JS:

```
    // this script shows how you can get info about the game
    var game = $('div.slashc-memory-game'); // get the game
    var info = $('p#info').find('span'); // get the info box
    var playAgain = $('a#play-again').css('visibility', 'hidden'); // get the play again link
    // format time like hh:mm:ss
    var formatTime = function(s)
    {
        var h = parseInt(s / 3600), m = parseInt((s - h * 3600) / 60); s = s % 60;
        return (h < 10 ? '0' + h : h) + ':' + (m < 10 ? '0' + m : m) + ':' + (s < 10 ? '0' + s : s);
    }
    // listen for game 'done' event 
    game.bind('done', function(e)
    {
        // show basic stats
        var stats = game.slashcMemoryGame('getStats');
        info.html('Success ! Number of clicks : ' + stats.numClicks + ', elapsed time : ' + formatTime(parseInt(stats.time / 1000)) + '.');
        playAgain.css('visibility', 'visible'); // show link
    });
    // play again action
    playAgain.click(function(e)
    {
        playAgain.css('visibility', 'hidden'); // hide link
        info.html('Memory Game, click to reveal images'); // reset text
        game.slashcMemoryGame('restart'); // restart game
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lynda333/ZXMUB/)

Comment: `SyntaxError: missing } after function body`

Comment: It doesn't make a lot of sense to set up a fiddle that doesn't mimic the actual problem.

Comment: Your site works fine for me. The fiddle, however, is full of copy-and-paste errors

Comment: Your code works fine.. so does the 'Play Again' link - Chrome 21.0.1180.83 m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing $() with jQuery() and see if you continue to get this error. The error indicating that it isn't a function means that either the jQuery file was not loaded yet or the $ name was freed intentionally.

If jQuery() function doesn't work, make sure that you are loading the jQuery file before your script block/file.

Comment: @Lynda: Together with the particular error message you're getting, it means that somewhere something is assigning to `$`, which is a problem.  Look for `$ = ...` and fix it.

Answer (score 1):

as fiddle automaticly adds the onload function, your code was actually working fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ZXMUB/5/

All i did was uncomment the first line where the game variable is beeing assigned, and remove closing `</script>` tag from the js window.

Are you sure on your actual site the code is inside a $(document).ready function (or something similar) and the jQuery library gets loaded properly?

Answer (score 0):

Your code was missing a document ready handler. Updated:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZXMUB/1/

Answer (score -1):

wrap your code in a "ready" function, like so

```
$(function(){  

 ...

});
```

Your code is executing before jquery is loaded.

Comment: This doesn't make sense.  If `$` isn't a function, how does wrapping an invalid call in another invalid call to `$` help?

Comment: I will point out, though, that the game isn't actually firing a "done" event, by all appearances.

Comment: As far as I know, jquery looks specifically for the `$(function())`, and  `$(document).ready(function()..)` things and binds them to the dom loaded events. To be honest, I don't actually know how it achieves this.

Comment: Absolutely not.  `$()` is just a regular function call.  If `$` doesn't exist when you try to call it, you'll get an error.  jQuery doesn't "look for" anything; there's no magic.  If jQuery hasn't been loaded before your script executes, you can't call jQuery methods, like binding to `document` `ready`.

Comment: I suppose that makes sense. So the magic is really just waiting for the Dom itself to be fully loaded, which in this case shouldn't "really" be a problem. Thanks for the clarification, I hadn't thought through it very much. If you run into `$ undefined` errors, I guess checking for `jQuery` and waiting is the appropriate response.